# Memory size exhausted when extending WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, errors

I tried to create a class that extends WP_Query, but I got this error:

`Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted`

I've increased the memory size in wp-config.php but that doesn't affect.

Here is my code:

```
class WPO_Query extends WP_Query {
    var $post_type = 'wp_order';

    public function __construct( $args = array() ) {
    }

    public function query( $data = array() ) {
        return parent::__construct( $data );
    }
}
```

and

```
$queries = new WPO_Query();
$orders = $queries->query( array( 'some' => 'data' ) );
```

But I won't get a error, when I use parent::__construct inside class __construct.
I hope you guys answer me instead vote me down.

Comment: What do you actually have instead of "some => data" and what happens if you use wp_query instead of your class?

Comment: Put `parent::__construct( $args );` in the `__construct` (no return) and `return parent::__query( $data );` in the `query`. Presumably you want to always set the post_type? Then put `$args['post_type'] = $this->post_type;` in the `__construct` before calling the parent.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I set required info.

Comment: @bonger Thanks a lot, worked, but `query` instead of `__query`. Write it as an answer.